# mongodb query in two different arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I have been going through the mongodb querying inside an array. I have gotten the example they give to work for me for querying a single array. But how would this work if I had two different arrays and wanted to combine them into a single query? for example item1 and item2 were two different arrays.

```
# example given in mongodb document
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } } )

# example of query of what I am trying achieve query two arrays 
db.inventory.find( { item1: { $in: [ item1_value ] } { item2: { $in: [ item2_value ] } } )
```

mongodb reference doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

I should also mention that I am using mongodb to get the idea of what the command would look like, but ultimately this command should work for pymongo as this command will be executed via pymongo.

```
# correct query example as given by Moshe
db.inventory.find({ 
      $or: [ 
             { item1: { $in: [ item1_value ] }}, 
             { item2: { $in: [ item2_value ] }}
       ]
});
```

Comment: You should note that if your `itemX_value` are actually only single values and not arrays themselves then you do not need `$in` just to search a document property that is an array. So unless the argument to `$in` needs to be a "list" then you just do. `.find({ '$or': [ { 'item1: 1 }, {'item2': 2 } ]})`. `$in` if for "argument lists" `.find({ '$or': [ { 'item1': { '$in': [1,2] } }, { 'item2': { '$in': [1,2] } } ] })`. MongoDB does not care if `'item1'` is actually an array itself, since it will simply search it's members for the "singular" supplied value. And yes the python syntax is identical

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB "OR" SYNTAX:

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

In your case:

```
db.inventory.find({ 
      $or: [ 
             { item1: { $in: [ item1_value ] }, 
             { item2: { $in: [ item2_value ] }
       ]
});
```

Comment: I think your correct, but when I run this as a query i keep getting ... as if syntax is not completely terminating the command.

Comment: @Matt I had my syntax wrong, I mixed up `]` with `}`, it should work now.

Comment: hmm, this is what is killing me with mongodb. the syntax is a bit pain full. I tried this as well seems to be same issue. seeing ... I think { item1: { $in: [ item1_value ] } was missing a bracket because the outermost bracket only matched to the bracket before the $in. I closed that and still seeing issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have spent days figuring out this syntax. Their was one small syntax error but pretty easy to figure out with your example. I will show your answer in my question example with updated syntax. Again thanks so much.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.